# Comparing Strings In node js "UTF-16"

Tags: c#, node.js, string, npm, utf-16

I am new to Node.js. And need a npm package or some module to compare to string in UTF-16 format.

In C# I have the following function:

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    var myComparer = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("en-US");
    return myComparer.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.Ordinal);
}
```

I want the same behavior in this c# code to be written in Node.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`String.prototype.localeCompare(compareString[, locales[, options]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Your equivalent might be `x.localeCompare(y, "en-US")`.

Comment: This one Worked Perfectly Thanks